# Apply function on each element of a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, apply

I have a list of matrices.

(below is a simplified example, I actually have a list of 3 matrices, the first one being in 2D, while the second and third ones are in 3D)

```
> a <- matrix(-1:2, ncol = 2)
> b <- array(c(-2:5), dim=c(2, 2, 2))
> c_list <- list(a,b)
> c_list
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    1
[2,]    0    2

[[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -2    0
[2,]   -1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5
```

I'd like to apply the function max(0,c_list) to each and every element (without a loop), in order to have the same type of object as "c_list" but with the negative values replaced by zeros.

```
> output
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    2

[[2]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5
```

I've managed to do it for a matrice or for a list with mapply or lapply, but not for a list of matrices.

Answer : either Sotos' answer

```
output <- lapply(c_list, function(i)replace(i, i < 0, 0))
```

or Moody_Mudskipper's answer

```
output <- lapply(c_list,pmax,0)
```

Comment: `lapply(c, function(i)replace(i, i < 0, 0))`

Comment: Your code for matrix b is flawed.

Comment: You're right jaySf, i've fixed it. Thx for the comment.

Comment: what do you want to do with your 3D matrix ?

Comment: better to use `lapply(c,function(i) pmax(i,0))` than the `apply` variant

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Each matrix keeps count of a population ; one can move in 2 dimensions and the others can move in 3 dimensions. I apply an advection-reaction-diffusion model on them using Euler's method, hence I need to ensure that I have positive numbers.

Comment: I believe that my answer and Soto's should work on 3D arrays but it'd have been nice to have one in your sample data

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You're right, I should have put a 3D matrix, I'll edit my question.
Every answer work for 2D matrices, but only Sotos' and Moody_Mudskipper's answer work for a 3D matrix.

Comment: Thx @Sotos for your answer.

Comment: See below, rewritten because I like code golf :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pmax`, it will preserve the format of the source matrix and vectorized so faster than looping with `max`.

```
lapply(c_list,pmax,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` and `lapply`:

```
a <- matrix(-1:2, ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(-3:0, ncol = 2)
c <- list(a,b)

d <- lapply(c, function(m) {
  apply(m, c(1, 2), function(x) max(0, x))
})
```

Output:

```
> d
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, it works well for the example I gave. 
Unfortunatly I should have given at least one 3D matrix in my example, hence I edited my question.